# AngularJS: Name a variable using another's variable value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to AngularJS and I'm still exploring its possibilities. Currently I'm stuck with this problem: How can I name a variable using another's variable value?

For example I have something like this in my controller:

```
    $scope.item_foo = 'Foo';
    $scope.item_bar = 'Bar';
```

I can access the values with this:

```
    {{item_foo}}
    {{item_bar}}
```

So far so good, but now I want to display them dynamically. I have an object with 'foo' and 'bar' and I loop it with ngRepeat. How can I do something like that:

```
    {{item_{{variable_with_value_foo_or_bar}}}} // should print Foo and Bar
```

Thank you for any of your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your template, `this` refers to the current scope, so you can do:

```
{{ this[ 'item_' + variable_with_value_foo_or_bar ] }}
```

There are probably better ways to perform what you're trying to do, but hopefully this answers your question.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like it would be better to use an object to store the data, rather than a bunch of things at the `$scope` level...:

```
$scope.item = {foo: 'Foo', bar: 'Bar'};
// ...
$scope.variable_with_value_foo_or_bar = 'foo';
```

Then access with:

```
{{item[variable_with_value_foo_or_bar]}}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually, my problem is not as easy as I wrote. It has a specific reason why I'm doing this. I'm sure it's not "best practice", but I'm still learning :)